# Npm Install giving errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, command-line-interface

Please help, I was trying to run npm install on a clone project but was getting a lot of errors on my terminal. All i did was npm install inside the supposed folder but was still getting errors. The error messages is below this message. thanks

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\DevcareerReactTasks\votingtask2\Devcareer_voting_system\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\DevcareerReactTasks\votingtask2\Devcareer_voting_system\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\DevcareerReactTasks\votingtask2\Devcareer_voting_system\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DevcareerReactTasks\\votingtask2\\Devcareer_voting_system\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\DevcareerReactTasks\votingtask2\Devcareer_voting_system\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.2 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN big-brother-dev-career@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN big-brother-dev-career@1.0.0 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-21T10_19_34_986Z-debug.log
`
```

Comment: As far as I can see *Python* is missing. Install it [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Comment: Your dependency `node-sass` requires `node-gyp` which needs python to be installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/56#issuecomment-308739624) method?

*npm --add-python-to-path='true'*